# Liferay: what is the relationship and difference between ActionRequest, RenderRequest and PortletRequest?

Tags: liferay, portlet, liferay-6

What is the relationship and difference between `ActionRequest`, `RenderRequest` and `PortletRequest`?

Can we get instance of one from another?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `PortletRequest` is the parent of both. An `ActionRequest` and a `RenderRequest` are both different types of `PortletRequest` objects.

An `ActionRequest` is valid during the action processing phase of the portlet. During this phase, the portlet hasn't completely decided how it is going to render itself, be it minimized, maximized, in edit mode or in veiw mode, etc.

On the other hand, the `RenderRequest` is valid during the rendering phase of the portlet. At this point, the portlet knows how it is going to render itself, and certain changes such as window state, are not allowed.

If you want to pass the params from action to render, you would need to set the `ActionResponse` using

```
response.setRenderParameter(key,val);
```

Then this is available in the corresponding `RenderRequest`.

[Answer was found here](http://www.coderanch.com/t/203777/Portals-Portlets/java/different-requests-purpose)