# ActionRequest vs RenderRequest

Tags: liferay, portlet

I've read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12745786/liferay-what-is-the-relationship-and-difference-between-actionrequest-renderre) that actionrequest is only valid during the action phase and RenderRequest is only valid during the render phase. However if I set actionREquest.setAttribute("object", myobject) I can access this object from my JSP, which I understand is the render phase right? How is this possible and how does this fit with the answer I link?

Answer (score 1):

While `ActionRequest` and `RenderRequest` are distinct classes/objects, they all relate to the same request handling cycle. The main difference is that `ActionRequest` allows you to change state, `RenderRequest` does not any more.

While only one portlet on the page can handle an action (per single HTTP request), all portlets on the page typically render to make up the whole markup of the page. That's what the separation of action/render brings you in the portlet world. Servlets didn't have this because one servlet was always meant to render the whole page on every single request anyway. Portlets can render (which they most often do) and they can change state (which they typically do in the action phase)

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't forget that after an action-phase, portlet lifecycles proceed toward render-phase.
Try to watch the image in this blog post (the first I found by a google search): http://haitaoblog.blogspot.it/2011/05/portlets-portal.html

So JSP can access to both attributes in request.

On the other hand, if you need to access in the render phase to an action RENDER parameter, you have to set it inside your action code

```
actionResponse.setRenderParameter("parameter-name", "value");
```

Comment: Well I don't understand then, what EXACTLY is the render phase? Why not use request attribute always?

Comment: Simplifying, action can be called just on data submit (and just once per time, eg. for data writing), while render can be called multiple times. Request and Response are two different concept and object (and you are not guarentee you will have all you request parameters in next renders, if an action is called on another portlet in the same page). If you need to understand EXACTLY, you have to read portlet specification https://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=286 or a tutorial explaining in detail a portlet lifecycle. I hope my answer can be clarifying for you.